# (node:2824) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: role is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my discord bot working again but he is old and in the old version this works but I have seen in other post to make this work I need put `member.role.add` but here I put the role from `let role = message.mentions.roles.first();`.

```js
if (comando === "addrole") {
    if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["✨Pequeno Chefinho✨", "✔️Micro Chefinho✔️"].includes(r.name)))
        return message.reply("Desculpe, você não tem permissão para usar isto!");
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!member)
        return message.reply("Por favor mencione um membro válido deste servidor");
    let role = message.mentions.roles.first();
    if (!role)
        return message.reply("Por favor mencione uma role deste servidor.")
    await member.addRole(role).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following:

```js
message.member.roles.some()
// to
message.member.roles.cache.some()
```

```js
member.addRole()
// to
member.roles.add()
```

**Modified Code**

```js
if (comando === "addrole") {
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => ["✨Pequeno Chefinho✨", "✔️Micro Chefinho✔️"].includes(r.name)))
        return message.reply("Desculpe, você não tem permissão para usar isto!");
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!member)
        return message.reply("Por favor mencione um membro válido deste servidor");
    let role = message.mentions.roles.first();
    if (!role)
        return message.reply("Por favor mencione uma role deste servidor.")
    await member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
```

For more information, read the [Discord.js migration guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html) or the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).